# How do I get a number based on the numbers on the end of a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I have couple of strings which I want to separate out the numbers from last position. If the string doesn't end with a number, `0` or `false` should be returned.

Here are some examples:

- string `"A1C10"` should return `10`
- string `"20AX23"` should return `23`
- string `"15AZC"` should return `0` or `false`

Comment: seems like a simple problem with many simple solutions - have you tried any

Comment: `yourString.match(/[0-9]+$/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `match` here:

```js
var inputs = ["A1C10", "20AX23", "15AZC"];
var outputs = inputs.map(x => x.match(/\d+$/) ? x.match(/\d+$/)[0] : "0");
console.log(outputs);
```

For your new requirement, we can split the input on `(?<=\D)(?=\d*$)`:

```js
var inputs = ["A1C10", "20AX23", "15AZC"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    var parts = inputs[i].split(/(?<=\D)(?=\d*$)/);
    if (parts.length == 1) parts.push("0");
    console.log(inputs[i] + " => " + parts);
}
```

Comment: This works for me, I need to separate out the remaining string except last trailing numbers. 
Ex- in above example A1C10 -- I should separate A1C string. For 20AX23 -- I should separate 20AX

Comment: Great, and that sounds like a new requirement not mentioned in your original question.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Can you please elaborate this concern and send here the new way to separate out string.

Comment: @PradipSolace I have given you an option for your other requirement.

Comment: Instead of matching the regex twice you could use `x.match(/\d+$/)?.[0] || "0"`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ... my comment comes with no intension of nitpicking. I just feel invited by a line like ... `x.match(/\d+$/) ? x.match(/\d+$/)[0] : "0"` ... to take up the cudgels on behalf of the often overlooked [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) ... where its usage would change the expression to ... `(/\d+$/).test(x) ? x.match(/\d+$/)[0] : "0"`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Agree completely, and making two regex API calls is ugly.  I only did it to get the one liner.  My "second" answer looks a lot better from a code reuse point of view.